# how to use both parameters and hard-code the servers list through powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I am trying to create a script which should run using parameter and without parameter should result for for multiple list:
Ex: I have a function under which I gave param as servername which is working fine for single server ad fetching the results.
(RestoreFileList -servername XXXXXXXXXXX1)

If I do not want to give a parameter as servername and output should result full set of servers list data
Ex : Restorefilecount

Am i missing something between parameter and serverlist condition which should fetch the results, Any help on this?

Script *************

```
function Restorefilecount()
{
[cmdletbinding()]
param(
[Parameter(position = 0,mandatory = $false)]
[string] $Servername
)
$servername = @()
$servername = ('XXXXXXXX1', 'XXXXXXXXX2', 'XXXXXXXXX3', 'XXXXXXXXXX4')
$result = Invoke-Client -ComputerName $Servername -ScriptBlock {
$Server = HOSTNAME.EXE
$Query = @'
Select @@ServerName AS ServerName , name,(SUBSTRING(NAME ,15,3) * 100 ) / 100 AS 
file,state_desc,user_access_desc FROM master.sys.databases where name like 'TKT' ORDER BY 2
'@
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $Server -Database master -Query $Query
}
```

Comment: That's improper syntax for the function, it's either an inline/simple function, `function name(){..}`, or `function name {Param()}`, not both. There's two ways to go about this efficiently. Cast the type of `string` as `string[]` and assign the values directly to that parameter, or...use the automatic variable of `$psboundparameters` to check for the key using `.ContainsKey()`

Comment: Tried with string[], able to fetch the full list of servers but when i tried using with parameter for single server getting full list of servers data. Any way to use both parameter and without parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on [Abraham Zinala](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14903754/abraham-zinala)'s helpful comments:

It looks like you're simply looking to **define a parameter's *default value***:

```
function Restore-FileCount {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param(
    [string[]] $Servername = @('XXXXXXXX1', 'XXXXXXXXX2', 'XXXXXXXXX3', 'XXXXXXXXXX4')
  )
  # ...
  $Servername # Output for demo purposes
}
```

Note how the parameter type had to be changed from `[string]` to `[string[]]` in order to support an *array* of values.

Incidental changes:

- Since you're using a `param(...)` block to define your parameters (which is generally preferable), there is no need to place `()` after the function name (`Restorefilecount()`) - while doing so doesn't cause a syntax error as long as there's nothing or only whitespace between `(` and `)`, note that you declare parameters *either* via a `param(...)` block *or* via `function foo(...)`; also, in parameter-less functions `()` is never needed - see the conceptual [about_Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions#syntax) help topic.
- I've inserted a hyphen (`-`) in your function name, to make it conform to PowerShell's naming convention.
- I've omitted `[Parameter(position = 0, mandatory = $false)]`, because what this attribute instance specifies amounts to the *default* behavior (all parameters are non-mandatory by default, and `Position=0` is implied by `$ServerName` being the *first* (and only) parameter).